# Python HELP! - Divide two (random.randint) values

Tags: python, random

```
import time
import random

print ("\nWelcome to this game, Player One - Please Enter Your Name ↓ ")
Player1 = input()
print ("\nHello", Player1 ,",Please hold on!")

print (" \nWelcome, Player Two - Please Enter Your Name ↓ ")
Player2 = input()
print ("\nHello", Player2 ,",Lets Begin")

print("Who Will Be Going First?")
first = input()

if first == Player1:
    print("\nDecrypting Data")
    time.sleep(2)

    print("\nData Successfully Decrypted")
    time.sleep(3)

    print("\nConnecting to attached proxy")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("\nConnecting to attached proxy....")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("\nConnecting to attached proxy........")
    time.sleep(3)

    print("\nSuccessfully Connected")
    time.sleep(2)

    divide=float(random.randint(1,4))
    divde2=float(random.randint(1,12))

    print("Hi", divide / divide2)
```

My task is to get two `random.randint` values which are:

1. The first from 1 to 4
2. The second from 1 to 12

The second random value should be divided by the first random value and the result must be rounded down.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong operator. `%` is the modulo sign. You want to use `/` which is the sign for division in Python. In your code, `print("Hi", divide % divide2)` should be changed to `print("Hi", divide / divide2)`. You can use the `int()` operator to round it down, but I think you'll want your code to produce decimals. Also you will get an error because you messed up name the `divide2` variable. You named it `divde2`, so you will need to change this also.

Answer (score 1):

The `%` operator is modulo, not division even though it kind of looks like it would be. Division is `/`. <strike>It automatically rounds down though, so no need to do anything there.</strike> oh didn't realize you had python 3. Then you have to use int div: `//`.

Make sure that you also understand that `randint` is not inclusive of the end value.